# Look up a table having 1 million records using Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, lookup

My database table(geo ip lookup) is having 7 columns,of which 2 columns constitute < composite-id>.
Now when i lookup for a value using first 2 coloumns it takes me **12-14 seconds** to fetch a record..

My DAO code looks like this:

```
String queryString = "from Igeo igeo where igeo.ip_from <= " + ip
            + "and igeo.ip_to >= " + ip;

    Query q = session.createQuery(queryString);
    List<Igeo> igeoList = q.list();

    if(igeoList.size() > 0){
        Igeo igeo = igeoList.get(0);

        ISP = igeo.getIsp();
        ...
        ...         
    }
```

*Igeo = class in java represnting table

**Record is fetched when ip lies between values of composite-id columns eg.

ip_from = 1 ; ip_to = 3 ; ip = 2;

so above row will be returned

This table is only used to read records ,please suggest me a queryString which is more efficient than above

Comment: This is not just query layer/hibernate layer, you need to fine-tune DB also by adding index on lookup fields etc., 1 million records is database headache than query (it seems your query is simple select, so I would concentrate more on database, unless some hidden details)

Comment: can you share some link on how to do that?

Comment: It depends on database vendor. For example http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_database_Performance_Tuning_FAQ

Answer (score 4):

First remove hibernate and run your query in a query browser and see how long it takes to return.  If it takes the same amount of time it's not Hibernate.  It's the performance of the database.  Make sure you add indexes onto the two columns ip_from and ip_to.  You can also execute a query plan on your query to see what the database is running under the hood and try and optimize the query plan.

I would suggest NOT using concatenation onto your query as you are.  That produces a security hole allowing potential SQL injection from outside parties.  It's better to use the following:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Igeo igeo where igeo.from_ip >= ? and igeo.to_ip <= ?");
q.setString( 0, ip );
q.setString( 1, ip );
```

You could also used named parameters which might shorten it up a bit more.

Comment: my first 2 coloumns are unique and sorted can you suggest a binary queryString which i can use with hibernate

Comment: @David your comment doesn't make much sense.  Are you asking how to specify query parameters that aren't strings, but some other data type?  After looking at your code I don't understand what your query should return?  Are you trying to find a single row or multiple rows?  Effectively I think your query will return every row in the DB so maybe your query is just illogical badness.  What are you trying to actually accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

If the table IGeo does not contain overlapping ranges of ip_from and ip_to, you might try this

```
    String queryString = "FROM Igeo igeo"
        +  " WHERE igeo.ip_to >= " + ip
        +  " ORDER BY igeo.ip_to";
```

Then check the first item in the list (to see that ip_from <= ip).

Even if the table could contain overlapping ranges of ip_from, ip_to, I bet the above HQL will run faster.

`<`Aside`>` You really should not concatenate a raw string like "ip" into HQL or SQL. It leads to SQL Injection Attack vulnerabilities. Use a query parameter instead`<`/Aside`>`

Also, verify that your database has an index on the column corresponding to Igeo.ip_to.

Sounds to me from your description, that the database has a primary key of Igeo.ip_from + IGeo.ip_to. If the values of ip_from and ip_to are not overlapping, that does not seem to be normalized. You should need only a single column for the primary key. If you have chosen to use both columns as a primary key, the above query will benefit by adding a single index.

Some databases will perform better if you add an index containing all the columns in the table, starting with ip_to and ip_from. (This enables the database to satisfy the query by accessing only the index). Not sure if MySQL can optimize to this extent, but I know DB2 and Oracle will provide this.

Comment: can you point me to a page which shows how to use indexes with hibernate Or
How to write a binary saerch query in hibernate if it exists

Comment: Dude your query never returned anything,as i guess order by clause choked server memory for million records